How to Add Additional Control Plane Nodes to an Existing Kubernetes Cluster?
I'm experimenting with setting up multiple control planes in a Kubernetes cluster.
I successfully created the first control plane and initialized it using the following command:
sudo kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint "$LOAD_BALANCER_IP” --upload-certs --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16

After running the command, the kubelet started successfully, and I received the following message:
You can now join any number of control-plane nodes by running the following command as root on each node:

    kubeadm join 192.168.0.200:6443 --token 9vr73a.a8uxyaju799qwdjv \
      --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:7c2e69131a36ae2a042a339b33381c6d0d43887e2de83720eff5359e26aec866 \
      --control-plane --certificate-key f8902e114ef118304e561c3ecd4d0b543adc226b7a07f675f56564185ffe0c07
    
    Please note that the certificate-key gives access to cluster-sensitive data. Keep it secret!
    As a safeguard, uploaded certs will be deleted in two hours. If necessary, you can use the following command to upload certs again:
    
    kubeadm init phase upload-certs

Additionally, to join worker nodes, I can use:
kubeadm join 192.168.0.200:6443 --token 9vr73a.a8uxyaju799qwdjv \
  --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:7c2e69131a36ae2a042a339b33381c6d0d43887e2de83720eff5359e26aec866

My Questions:

Do I need to run kubeadm init again on a second control-plane node to join it to the existing control plane?
Or do I just use the kubeadm join command with the --control-plane flag?

How do I generate the join command for adding control-plane nodes at will?
For worker nodes, I can use the following command to regenerate the join token:
kubeadm token create --print-join-command


Is there an equivalent for control-plane nodes, or how do I regenerate the join command to add more control planes after initialization?
Any guidance or best practices for adding additional control planes to an existing Kubernetes cluster would be greatly appreciated!


You cannot execute kubeadm init on second control-plane if you wish to join existing cluster. You can use kubeadm join for control-plane nodes printed by kubeadm init (for the duration of its token).

Joining new node as part of control-plane after token expires or kubernetes cert is automatically removed for safety reasons (without determining which one is required):

Generate new token (and print join command) using

kubeadm token create --print-join-command

Upload cluster certs again by executing

kubeadm init phase upload-certs --upload-certs

Use the output of both to create new kubeadm join command (copy output of first command as-is, add --control-plane --certificate-key  and the certificate checksum from second command).



Extra info: please remember that control plane consisting of just two nodes is degraded (meaning it will not offer any High Availability). 3 control-plane nodes is minimum for HA capabilities.
